# Move drop-down menu item?

Tags: notepad++

I have a submenu item in notepad++ that I want to be a top-level item.  I want to move some often-used, expandable/expanded submenu items to the primary menu.

For example, instead of: Plugins>NppFTP.

I want to have: NppFTP.

Answer (score 0):

For plugin developers it is not possible to place some submenus/menu items at the top level menu. Because public API of Notepad++ does not allow that.